# referencing users by primary key in class based view django

Tags: python, django

So I am building a blog website and I want to reference a detailed profile view after the user who is interacting with the website clicks the link to the detail profile view of an author
Now,

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user'
```

So in urls.py, I add primary key

```
path('profile/<int:pk>', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile-detail')
```

Now in html, I say like:

```
{{ user.username }}
<img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" >
{{ user.email }}
```

Now, what happens is, in my homepage where I have created like 30 blogs and each of them have a link to view the profile of author. Now I have just created 2 authors and those two posted those 30 blogs. Now If I like go to the author's page of 30th blog, it takes me to the route http://localhost:8000/profile/30  So it is creating urls with primary key 1 to 30 but I have primary keys for my authors' just 1 and 2. So, it is giving error that page not found. So I want  the link to take me to the url that refers to the profile of an author. Like even if I click on the 30th post, it should take me to author id 2 if that post is written by that author. So it should take me to for example: http://localhost:8000/profile/2 even if I click on the 30th or 20th post.

So what is wrong here? Why the primary key here is referring to the primary key of the blogs? And how to solve this problem?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the links in the template for your blog listing.

Comment: Okay, yep. So I had   <a href="{% url 'profile-detail' post.id %}">  for referencing. I get it. but what should I use instead of post.id there? I mean how to reference that author that have written that blog? and also, post.id refers to the primary key of the blog to be clear here

Comment: That depends on what is in your models, but sensible design would be to have a Foreign Key field referencing the author, so the `post.id` would become `post.author.id` or something similar - as I said it depends on exactly how you've got the models set up.